# Podium Style Sorting in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

Given that I have array of hashes, how can I sort them (using ruby) into a podium style (using their created_at value) like in the image below?

```
[
  { created_at: "DATETIME", src: "..." },
  { created_at: "DATETIME", src: "..." },
  { created_at: "DATETIME", src: "..." },
  { created_at: "DATETIME", src: "..." }
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I expect most solutions to perform a simple sort to get an array in ascending order, and then iterate through this array to generate the 'podium'. I hope some people will imagine a solution in one pass. I'm working on this...

Comment: Can you specify what you're looking for the current answers don't provide?

Comment: @SirDarius, since you seemed interested, I got my answer working without having sort twice (it's an implementation of insertion sort).

Comment: @agmin I was just seeing what all solutions were possible and how people approached them differently. All these solutions do what I asked.

Comment: @KyleDecot your bounty will expire in 4 hours if you don't manually award it to anyone or accept one of the answers.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCashwell Good looking out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`arr.sort_by{|a| a['created_at']}.inject([]){ |r, e|  r.reverse << e }`

Fun problem!

Comment: Prettiest, for sure — no ugly indices. imo, no need your first 3 lines.

Comment: Agreed that this is the prettiest solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work:

`[{:created_at=>2013-11-13 10:56:55 -0500},
 {:created_at=>2013-11-13 11:58:55 -0500},
 {:created_at=>2013-11-13 10:35:55 -0500},
 {:created_at=>2013-11-13 11:57:55 -0500},
 {:created_at=>2013-11-13 11:35:55 -0500},
 {:created_at=>2013-11-13 11:01:55 -0500}]`

Comment: your hash has sym keys thats why. use a[:created_at].

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure you could compress this further, but something like this would do the trick:

```
# Your initial array
item_array = [{...}]
count = 0

# Sort it first, then stagger results to each side of the array
podium_sorted = item_array.sort_by{|a| a['created_at']}.inject([]) do |arr, item|
  count += 1
  count % 2 == 0 ? arr.unshift(item) : arr.push(item)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't averse to using a completely mental solution, I quite like this one:

```
zipped = (1..5).zip [:push, :unshift].cycle
# => [[1, :push], [2, :unshift], [3, :push], [4, :unshift], [5, :push]]

[].tap { |result| zipped.each { |val, op| result.send op, val } }
# => [4, 2, 1, 3, 5]

module Enumerable
  def to_podium
    [].tap { |r| (zip [:push, :unshift].cycle).each { |v, o| r.send o, v } }
  end
end

(1..10).to_podium
# => [10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

And showing it in action:

```
test_input = (1..5).map { |i| { created_at: i, some_val: rand(100) } }.shuffle
# => [{:created_at=>3, :some_val=>69},
#     {:created_at=>5, :some_val=>15},
#     {:created_at=>2, :some_val=>89},
#     {:created_at=>4, :some_val=>77},
#     {:created_at=>1, :some_val=>54}]

test_input.sort_by { |e| e[:created_at] }.to_podium
# => [{:created_at=>4, :some_val=>77},
#     {:created_at=>2, :some_val=>89},
#     {:created_at=>1, :some_val=>54},
#     {:created_at=>3, :some_val=>69},
#     {:created_at=>5, :some_val=>15}]
```

Comment: Not adverse at all to a solution from someone who admits to being (a little) mental.  This most definitely has earned an allocation of grey cells, in part for the tapping sound it emits. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
def podium_sort(array)
  array.sort_by{|h| h[:created_at]}.each_with_index.inject([]) do |out, (item, index)|
    index.odd? ? out.unshift(item) : out.push(item)
  end
end

podium_sort((1..10).map { |value| {created_at: Time.now - rand(value..100).minutes } })
=> [{:created_at=>2013-10-30 18:03:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 17:58:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 17:44:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 17:18:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 16:54:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 16:48:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 16:57:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 17:37:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 17:44:54 -0400},
 {:created_at=>2013-10-30 18:00:54 -0400}]
```

Comment: Nice and clean, Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using `Enumerable#partition`:

```
items     = [5,1,2,4,3].sort # use any sort method that is relevant
odd, even = items.each_with_index.partition{ |item,index| index.odd? }
podium    = even.reverse.push(*odd).map(&:first) # &:first to remove index
```

Probably slightly less efficient (have to build intermediate arrays), but more compact.

Moreover, the solution some people expose here can be rewritten more compactly as well :

```
items.sort.each_with_index.inject([]) do |podium,(item,index)|
  index.odd? ? podium.unshift(item) : podium.push(item)
end
```

which could be a nice extension to `Enumerable` or any enumerable class of your choice :

```
module Enumerable
  def podium(&block)
    items = block_given? ? sort : sort_by(&block)
    items.each_with_index.inject([]) do |podium,(item,index)|
      index.odd? ? podium.unshift(item) : podium.push(item)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This was my solution as well, with some small changes. I used `.map.with_index.partition` to be clear that I wanted to transform the array instead of relying on side effects. I used `(odd.reverse + even).map(&:first)` as the last line instead of splatting the array.

Comment: I think this solution reads the best (places least demand on the reader to understand), particularly with @Shepmaster's alternate last line.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a solution without having two sorts:

```
arr = [ { :created_at => ... }, { :created_at => ... }, ... ]
size = arr.count
poss = Array.new(size) { |i| i%2 == 0 ? size-(i/2+1) : i/2 }
final = [-1]*size
```

And then it's just a simple matter of applying an insertion sort to a non-linear map `poss`. So you would do things like:

```
arr.each do |val|
  poss.each_with_index do |pos, pos_index|
    if final[pos] == -1
      final[pos] = val
      break
    elsif final[pos][:created_at] < val[:created_at]
      tmp_val = final[pos]
      final[pos] = val
      poss[pos_index+1..size].each do |new_pos|
        if final[new_pos] == -1
          final[new_pos] = tmp_val
          break
        elsif final[new_pos][:created_at] < tmp_val[:created_at]
          tmp2_val = final[new_pos]
          final[new_pos] = tmp_val
          tmp_val = tmp2_val
        end
      end
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Very simply put, this is just an implementation of the insertion sort algorithm, only instead of mapping to a linear line, we're mapping to poss.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way

```
arr.sort_by { |h| h[:created_at] }.sort_by.with_index { |_,i| i.odd? ? -i : i }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Initializing variable to store the output
podium_sorted = []


# Assuming sorting has to be in descending order of created_at 
#(If you want it in ascending the just remove `reverse` from the below line)
sorted_array = input_array.sort_by { |record| record[:created_at] }.reverse
sorted_array.each_with_index do |record, index|
  index.even? ? podium_sorted << record : podium_sorted = [record] + podium_sorted
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution I came up with using Ruby's OpenStruct and a Mixin.

FWIW I added a key called given_order to your initial hash to for visual cue on printed output. Obviously this is unnecessary for the final problem.

```
require 'ostruct'

# compose a lightweight class and make it comparable
class SortableSeed < OpenStruct
  include Comparable
  def <=>(other)
    created_at <=> other.created_at
  end
end

# initial seed. src
seed = [
   { created_at: Time.now + 180, src: "...", given_order: "1" },
   { created_at: Time.now + 60,  src: "...", given_order: "2" },
   { created_at: Time.now + 240, src: "...", given_order: "3" },
   { created_at: Time.now,       src: "...", given_order: "4" },
   { created_at: Time.now + 320, src: "...", given_order: "5" }
]

# show inital arrangement
puts "Initial Seed (random order)\n"
puts seed
puts "\n"

# Create our structs from seed
structs = seed.map {|struct| SortableSeed.new(struct)}

# sort and out print them
puts "Podium Sort (by created_at)\n"
structs.sort.map {|struct| puts struct.inspect}
```

Output:

```
# Initial Seed (random order)
{:created_at=>2013-11-05 17:30:22 -0600, :src=>"...", :given_order=>"1"}
{:created_at=>2013-11-05 17:28:22 -0600, :src=>"...", :given_order=>"2"}
{:created_at=>2013-11-05 17:31:22 -0600, :src=>"...", :given_order=>"3"}
{:created_at=>2013-11-05 17:27:22 -0600, :src=>"...", :given_order=>"4"}
{:created_at=>2013-11-05 17:32:42 -0600, :src=>"...", :given_order=>"5"}

# Podium Sort (by created_at)
#<SortableSeed created_at=2013-11-05 17:27:22 -0600, src="...", given_order="4">
#<SortableSeed created_at=2013-11-05 17:28:22 -0600, src="...", given_order="2">
#<SortableSeed created_at=2013-11-05 17:30:22 -0600, src="...", given_order="1">
#<SortableSeed created_at=2013-11-05 17:31:22 -0600, src="...", given_order="3">
#<SortableSeed created_at=2013-11-05 17:32:42 -0600, src="...", given_order="5">
```

Fun problem.

Comment: I was unaware of `OpenStruct`, but no longer.  Very powerful.  +1

Answer (score 1):

```
def podium_sort arr
  arr.sort_by {|h| h[:created_at]}.map.with_index {|e,i|
    i.odd? ? [-i,e] : [i,e]}.sort.map(&:last)
end

arr = [
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:20:59 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:22:07 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:31 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:22:04 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:06 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:10 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:20:44 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:20:52 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:22:00 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:50 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:15 -0800}
]

podium_sort(arr) #=> [
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:22:04 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:50 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:15 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:06 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:20:52 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:20:44 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:20:59 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:10 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:21:31 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:22:00 -0800},
  {:created_at=>2013-11-05 22:22:07 -0800}
]
```

Edit: yet another:

```
def sel(a,t) a.select {|e| t = !t} end

def podium_sort(a)
  sel(a.sort!,true).reverse + sel(a,false)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort items, then grow the podium from the middle out.

```
def podium_sort(items)
  sorted = items.sort_by{|h|h[:created_at]}
  sorted.each_slice(2).reduce([]) { |podium, pair|
    [pair[1]] + podium + [pair[0]]
  }.compact
end
```

More variations, using `each_slice(2)`:

Sort items, build up left and right sides of podium, then combine.

```
def podium_sort(items)
  left = []
  right = []
  sorted = items.sort_by{|h|h[:created_at]}
  sorted.each_slice(2){|a,b| left.unshift(b); right << a}
  (left.compact + right)
end
```

Sort items, transpose pairs of columns into rows, then combine.

```
def podium_sort(items)
  sorted = items.sort_by{|h|h[:created_at]}
  sorted += [nil] if items.length.odd?
  right, left = sorted.each_slice(2).to_a.transpose
  (left.compact.reverse + right)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

having the array sorted by the created_at attribute we can just provide a method like

```
def podium_sort(array)
  result = []
  l = array.length / 2 + 1
  l.times do |i|
    result.push(array[2*i])
    result.unshift(array[2*i+1])
  end
  result.compact
end
```

EDIT

I did a benchmark on this solutions against the following two:

an implementation based on checking on every element of the array

```
def pod_if(ar)
  count = 0
  ar.sort_by{|a| a[:created_at]}.inject([]) { |arr, item|
    count += 1
    count % 2 == 0 ? arr.unshift(item) : arr.push(item); 
  }
end
```

and an implementation (@bonzofenix) with consecutive reverses. (the most elegant, but quite expensive)

```
def pod_reverse(arr)
  arr.sort_by{|a| a['created_at']}.inject([]){ |r, e| r.reverse << e }
end
```

For an array a of 100 hashes, the benchmark is:

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('zig_zag') { 1000000.times { podium_sort a } }
  x.report('if_based') { 1000000.times { pod_if a } }
  x.report('reverse') { 1000000.times { pod_reverse a } }
end
```

and the results where

```
               user        system    total      real
zig_zag        89.090000   0.490000   89.580000 (121.833205)
if_based       97.250000   0.230000   97.480000 (123.692612)
reverse       207.050000   0.610000  207.660000 (267.401497)
```

So in the end it all ends up on where we want to focus,

- The "consecutive reverses" implementation (IMHO) is very elegant, but it is remarkably slower.
- On the other hand the other two implementations seem to be on similar speed (the one based on the array's length, slightly better).

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
((0...A.length).select(&:odd?).reverse + (0...A.length).select(&:even?)).collect { |p| A.sort_by { |i| i[:created_at] }[p] }
```

Or, breaking it into more readable form:

```
podium = ((0...A.length).select(&:odd?).reverse + (0...A.length).select(&:even?)
sorted_array = A.sort_by { |i| i[:created_at] }
podium.collect { |p| sorted_array[p] }
```

Comment: The broken part is more performant as well as it avoids sorting the array again and again.

Comment: @Chandranshu: Right, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array normally and then run the following code:

```
result = []
a.each.with_index do |x, i|
  i.even? ? result.push(x) : result.unshift(x)
end
```

Another way of doing it:

```
a.push(nil) if a.size.odd?
a = a.each_slice(2).to_a.transpose
p (a.first.reverse + a.last).compact
```

Answer (score 0):

It's based on sign changes of (-1)**k. But there are 2 sorting :(

```
arr = [....]
k = - 1;
arr.sort_by{|item| item[:created_at]}.sort_by{|item| k *= -1; k*item[:created_at].to_time.to_i}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toggle = true
array.sort_by{|a| a['created_at']}.inject([]) do |r, e| 
    toggle  ? r.push(e) : r.unshift(e)
    toggle = !toggle
    r
end
```